# Copy file from Docker container to Github repository

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, docker-container, building-github-actions

I have a Dockerfile and a tex file in my repository. I use Github Actions to build an image(ubuntu 18.10 with packages for PDFLaTeX) and run a container, which gets main.tex and produces main.pdf with PDFLaTeX. So far everything seems to work OK, but the problem is I can't copy the pdf from container to repository. I tried using docker cp:

`docker cp pdf-creator:/main.tex .`

But it doesn't seem to work, as pdf doesn't appear in my repository. Can you think of any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

The `docker cp` command copies a file into *the local filesystem*. In the context of a GitHub action, this is just whatever virtual environment is being used to run your code: it has nothing to do with your repository.

The only way to add something to your repository is to `git add` the file, `git commit` the change, and `git push` the change to your repository (which of course requires providing your Action with the necessary credentials to push changes to your repository, probably using a GitHub Secret).

But rather than adding the file to your repository, maybe you want to look at support for [Artifacts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts)? This lets you save files generated as part of your workflow and make them available for Download.

The workflow step would look something like:

```
      - name: Archive generated PDF file
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: main.pdf
          path: /main.pdf
```

See the linked docs for more information.